# How to detect if the user doesn't allow Apple Health Kit Authorisation?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I am using **AppleHealthKit** in my application. Everything is working correctly. The problem is that I am not able to detect if the user taps **"Don't Allow"** button when asking for permission.

[image]

With this method, my application uses **HealthKit**, even though the user doesn't allow this.

```
requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(healthKitTypesToWrite, readTypes: healthKitTypesToRead) { (success, error) -> Void in
        if( completion != nil ) {
            completion(success:success,error:error)
        }
```

Apple Documentation:

[image]

So basically my question is how to detect this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot detect it, by design:

> To help prevent possible leaks of sensitive health information, your app cannot determine whether a user has granted permission to read data. If you are not given permission, it simply appears as if there is no data of the requested type in the HealthKit store.

(from [HKHealthStore](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKHealthStore_Class/))

Answer (score 5):

You can do this but only for one specific type and only for write data(u can do the same with other type too if u have to check them)

```
HKHealthStore *_healthStore;
HKQuantityType *stepsType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount];

HKAuthorizationStatus status = [_healthStore authorizationStatusForType:stepsType];

BOOL isActive;
switch (status) {
    case HKAuthorizationStatusSharingAuthorized:
        isActive = YES;
        break;
    case HKAuthorizationStatusSharingDenied:
        isActive = NO;
        break;
    case HKAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
        isActive = NO;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

NSLog(@"STATUS-------%@", isActive ? @"yes" : @"no");
```